# Is there a way to load flutter pages in background on launch

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app with 5 different pages, the issue is most of this pages are janky on first launch of my app but after going from page to page, everything smoothens out after. For instance, the hero widget is laggy until going back and forth on the pages.

Anyway to load all pages in the background, so all pages are in memory.

Comment: Not sure if it's a good idea to do that, but you can use the Dart const constructor as much as possible to create object a compile time https://www.learndartprogramming.com/fundamentals/constant-constructor-in-dart/

Comment: Check this doc - https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/rendering/shader

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Navigator.push()` to navigate pages, just simply use `Navigator.pushReplacement()`  instead of it.

Comment: Not what I am talking about. I need all my pages in the app to load to memory on first launch of my app.